# How to Force Download to use JPEG instead of JFIF

Tags: javascript, frontend

I'm creating a feature to export a graph from my website. On my local machine the images are being downloaded as JFIF's on my coworkers the images are properly being downloaded as JPEG's. I am aware that I can configure my local machine to change the extension. However, I don't want non-technical users to have to go through this process. Is there a way to ensure that images are downloaded on any machine as JPEG's?

Here is my code

```
const downloadGraph = () => {
  const element = document.getElementById('unique-id') as HTMLCanvasElement;
  saveImage(element, 'Title');
}

const saveImage = (canvas: HTMLCanvasElement, fileName: string) => {
   const url = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 1.0);
   download(url, fileName, )
}

const download = (url: string, fileName: string) => {
  const link = document.createElement("a");
  link.setAttribute("href", url);
  link.setAttribute("download", fileName);
  link.style.visibility = 'hidden';
  document.body.appendChild(link);
  link.click();
  document.body.removeChild(link);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify the `fileName` parameter (in both cases)

```
fileName.slice(0,fileName.lastIndexOf('.'))+'.jpg'
```

Comment: This completely solved my question, thank you!